# print the feature name for DecisionTree instead of column number

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How to print the column names, such as feature 1, feature 2, feature 3, feature 4, feature 5 or feature 6 instead of `-2`in the decision tree output.
The answer should be scalable, such as if someone had 500 columns+ or more.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature 1':X[:,0],
                                  'Feature 2':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3':X[:,2],
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})


y_train = df['Class']
X_train = df.drop('Class',axis = 1)


from sklearn.tree import _tree
# Using those arrays, we can parse the tree structure:

n_nodes = dt.tree_.node_count
children_left = dt.tree_.children_left
children_right = dt.tree_.children_right
feature = dt.tree_.feature
threshold = dt.tree_.threshold

new_X = np.array(X_train)

node_indicator = dt.decision_path(new_X)

# Similarly, we can also have the leaves ids reached by each sample.

leave_id = dt.apply(new_X)

# Now, it's possible to get the tests that were used to predict a sample or
# a group of samples. First, let's make it for the sample.

sample_id = 703
node_index = node_indicator.indices[node_indicator.indptr[sample_id]:
                                    node_indicator.indptr[sample_id + 1]]

print('Rules used to predict sample %s: ' % sample_id)
for node_id in node_index:
    if leave_id[sample_id] != node_id:
        continue

    if (new_X[sample_id, feature[node_id]] <= threshold[node_id]):
        threshold_sign = "<="
    else:
        threshold_sign = ">"

    print("decision id node %s : (For sample number [%s, %s] (= %s) %s %s)"
          % (node_id,
             sample_id,
             feature[node_id],
             new_X[sample_id, feature[node_id]],
             threshold_sign,
             threshold[node_id]))
```

> Rules used to predict sample 703: 
>   decision id node 11 : (For sample number [703, -2] (= -0.210092480919) > -2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `feature[node_id]` with `df.columns[feature[node_id]]` like this:

```
print("decision id node %s : (For sample number [%s, %s] (= %s) %s %s)"
      % (node_id,
         sample_id,
         X_train.columns[feature[node_id]],
         new_X[sample_id, feature[node_id]],
         threshold_sign,
         threshold[node_id]))
```

Comment: "Rules used to predict sample 703: decision id node 11 : (For sample number [703, feature 1] (= -0.210092480919) > -2.0)" is this the last split that determined the feature ? Thanks

Comment: @Victor In your case, yes thats the only split. Have you tried plotting the tree?

Comment: actually that's what I am trying to do now. Is it possible to plot a tree for that single instance rather that the whole tree ?

Comment: @Victor No. The closest you get is what you have done. But since no new information is being gained during prediction, the tree from the trained data will be used for single sample also.

Comment: any links to plotting the tree for DT for the above ?

Comment: @Victor Please read the edited comment above. And this is the link (which i think you have done in previous questions): http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165498/discussion-between-victor-and-vivek-kumar).